# QtDataVisualization not installed on linux

Tags: linux, qt5, qt-creator

Trying to develop a QtDataVisualization app on Ubuntu 16.04, but the qtcreator/compiler says QtDataVisualization is not installed. I installed Qt 5.13.0 through the online installer, specified option to include the QtDataVisualization add-on. Downloaded files include many named "*qtdatavisualization*". Added "QT += datavisualization" to my .pro file per the [Qt Data Visualization Known Issues](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qtdatavisualization-known-issues.html) page. Yet while qtcreator designer offers "QtDataVisualization 1.3" as an import, the import fails with designer error message 'found not working import... "QtDataVisualization" is not installed'. Manually editing the QML file with "import QtDataVisualization 1.3" also results in "QtDataVisualization not installed". Just to be sure, I retrieved, built, and installed the [qtdatavis3d repository](https://github.com/qt/qtdatavis3d) per [these instructions](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qtdatavisualization-getting-started.html). Yet qtcreator still gives "QtDataVisualization not installed" when I attempt to import it. Extremely annoying - I see others have reported similar problems on stackoverflow with no solution yet. Can anyone help? Thanks!